# How temporarily disable "needs_migration?" check when testing migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I've written the spec to test my migration but when I run it I got an error:

```
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError:

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

    bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

I've tried to disable the migration check in the `before` section but that check is running before all tests.

How to disable the migration check for testing purposes?

Comment: Interesting. I've never thought to test migrations before. Maybe I've been missing something...

Comment: Data is probably one of your most important assets so I would always test data migrations. Schema migrations which only use Rails built in functions I wouldn't test and trust the framework.

Comment: Please also share your code

Comment: @ChristianBruckmayer I was following this guide https://docs.gitlab.com/12.10/ee/development/testing_guide/testing_migrations_guide.html

Comment: I see! Looking at it, it seems they also recommend to mostly write tests only for data migrations. Have a look at my answer to abstract data migrations in a service class which would make your (testing) life a lot easier. Data migrations don't need to happen in a Rails migrations, in fact, it just makes your life more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing Rails migration is a bit of a pain so I would rather step back and think about if this needs to be in a Rails migration / tested in a Rails migration.

There are basically two different types of migrations

### Schema migrations

Use mostly Rails built in functions. Unless you do some handcrafted SQL I wouldn't bother testing this and trust the framework here.

### Data migrations

Data migrations are used to backfill or change data. As data is one of your most valuable assets and loosing or corrupting it is very painful I would definitely recommend to write tests for data migrations.

As mentioned, testing migrations is a bit of a pain so I would try to abstract the data migration code in it's own (service) class. Something like

```rb
class DataMigration::UpdateUsername
  def self.run
    new.run
  end

  def run
    User.all do |batch|
      user.update(name: user.name.capitalize)
    end
  end
end
```

You can now test the data migration like a normal class like this:

```rb
it 'does capitalize the name' do
  user = create(:user, name: 'name')

  DataMigration::UpdateUsername.run

  expect(user.reload.name).to eq('NAME')
end
```

Now we can use this class in our Rails migration or e.g. just use it in a Rake task. Using it in a Rake task also has the advantages that we can pass in parameters, run several data migrations in parallel (e.g. you have a large data set) or even in a background job which you can't in a Rails migration.

Example

```rb
class DataMigration::UpdateUsername
  def initialize(start_id:, finish_id:)
    @start_id = start_id
    @finish_id = finish_id
  end

  def run
    User.find_in_batches(start: start_id, finish: finish_id) do |batch|
      batch.each do |user|
        user.update(name: user.name.capitalize)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now we can create a custom task for this

```rb
namespace :db do
  desc "Runs user data migration"
  task :update_user, [:start, :finish] do |task, args|
    DataMigration::UpdateUsername.new(start_id: args[:start], finish_id: args[:finish])
  end
end

rake db:update_user[0, 10000]
rake db:update_user[10000, 20000]
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In `config/environments/test.rb` add the line

```
config.active_record.migration_error = false
```